# MySQL GORM Query says Slow Query and Its getting slow with more hits in Rest Api

Tags: go, go-gorm

I used **Gin GORM and MySQL** for a Get Rest Api Request. I also use go cache and Redis for better performance. But when I fetch data from MySQL database , Its says 'slow query' 1000MS in Gin log and Its getting slow when more hits by JMeter.

**This is the Query:**

'config.DB.Raw("SELECT * FROM Terms WHERE is_active = 1 limit 1").Scan(&Terms)'

My Gin log says slow query and I tested with JMeter , its really slow,
How can I improve this??

Comment: Do you have `INDEX(is_active)?  Do you care which row you get?  Are there any `TEXT` columns in the `*`?  Are you using `ENGINE=InnoDB`?  Are other connections busy with `Terms`, especially writing to it?

Comment: yes (is_active) is a index , yes Terms have 5 columns. I have only one row. i was not use ENgine=InnoDB I just used (var DB *gorm.DB) and "db, err := gorm.Open(mysql.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{ Logger: logger.Default.LogMode(logger.Silent), PrepareStmt: true, SkipDefaultTransaction: true, }) " and "DB=db" and no other connection is busy/ THIS IS THE LOG , ITS TAKES [16584.108ms] "SLOW SQL >= 200ms [16584.108ms] [rows:1] SELECT * FROM Terms WHERE is_active = 1 limit 1"

Comment: Only one row in the table?  All bets are off.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `SHOW TABLE STATUS`.